# Apple Watch: Check pair status?

Tags: ios, apple-watch

Is there a class available that will tell me if a watch is paired to a device?

I'm just looking for a simple yes/no check that will tell me if a watch is paired to a device.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793093/how-to-check-whether-iphone-and-apple-watch-are-connected

Comment: `WCSession.defaultSession().paired` will return you a `BOOL` but is only available in Watch OS 2 or later.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the WatchConnectivity (WC) framework to check the connections between iPhone and the paired Apple Watch, including pairing status.

Import WatchConnectivity in your code and then use the following code:

Swift:

```
if (WCSession.defaultSession().paired){
    // Paired
} else{
    // Not Paired
}
```

Objective-C:

```
if([WCSession defaultSession].paired){
    // Paired
} else{
    // Not Paired
}
```

Use the suitable code for each condition in Obj-C or Swift.

NOTE: WatchConnectivity framework is only available in watchOS 2. You can't get status of the paired Apple Watch in watchOS 1 (the old WatchKit).
*Make sure ur session is activated. This will return true only after session activated*