# how to get current distance between iPhone and paired Apple Watch

Tags: ios, apple-watch

is there any way to get distance between apple watch and paired iPhone. I am working on a test case in which .. iPhone and Apple Watch should be notified when distance between both devices got change.

Comment: Currently watchkit does not support anything like that.

Comment: But you can show whether it is paired or not. Check this for other info on this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27793093/how-to-check-whether-iphone-and-apple-watch-are-connected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You technically can't get the exact distance, but you can make one device act as a beacon and work on their Core Location proximity. You have up to three proximity states on which you can check the distance: `CLProximityImmediate` (i.e. the device are very close to each other), `CLProximityNear` (i.e. the devices are close to each other) and `CLProximityFar` (i.e. the devices are about to lose Bluetooth connection).

Comment: How do you check the proximity on Apple Watch? I can't recognize Beacons in WatchOS, so maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: This solution uses CLBeacon which is not available on WatchOS.