# Distance from Apple Watch to iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, core-location, apple-watch, watchos-2

How can you determine the distance between an `Apple Watch` and `iPhone`. [The question has been asked before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563937/how-to-get-current-distance-between-iphone-and-paired-iwatch), but with no good response. A [recent app got a lot of press](http://www.macrumors.com/2016/03/10/apple-watch-lookout-app-misplaced-iphone/) showing this feature.

The obvious way seems to be with a `CLBeaconRegion` and a beacon running on the phone, but `CLBeaconRegion` is not available on `watchOS`

The previous answer mentioned in the comments below was asked around the time of the `watchOS` 1.0 release. At that time I know it was not possible, but since then much more code can be set to run on the actual watch including limited `Core Location` support.